# QT: Change the name of the built executable

Tags: qt

Running QT Creator 2.4 on Mac OSX.

How do I change the name of the final .app file generated? It seems it's bound to the name of the .Pro file.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In your `.pro` file, use:

```
TARGET = name_of_application
```

Comment: Don't forget to remove files Makefile*  in your build folder, or a "NewApp.exe file doesn't exist" error will appear. In my installation, for some reason, the "Clean" button doesn't work so I need to remove the Makefiles manually.

Answer (score 4):

You can open the `.pro` file and change the Name in the `TARGET` variable.  The executable will be built as that name.

Comment: If my project name is myapp and the .pro file is myapp.pro, how to change the rename of the app folder and the .pro file ?!